# Как улучшить код, один за одним вызывающий несколько потоков, выполняющих методы разных классов?

Tags: c#

В Main() код для вызова функции
У меня есть много классов которые должны работать через Thread,
например:

```
//да что показывать всё просто в programs вызываю в Main все необходимые классы!)

using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test
{
   internal class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Thread s = new Thread(class.Go);
          s.Start();
          Thread s = new Thread(class2.Go);
          s.Start();
          Thread s = new Thread(class3.Go);
          s.Start();
         Thread s = new Thread(class4.Go);
         s.Start();
         Thread s = new Thread(class5.Go);
         s.Start();    
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы не писать так много для каждого класса, как можно это сделать лучше?

Comment: Этот код в одной функции, или в каждом классе свой? Если в одной функции, сделайте цикл.

Comment: Вызываю я всё это в 1 классе..

Comment: Тогда непонятно, почему не циклом. Покажите больше кода.

Comment: Да что показывать)).. Всё просто в program вызываю.. Вот и думаю как будет лучше чтобы не писать для каждого

Comment: У вас синтаксическая ошибка - четырехкратное повторное объявление переменной s

Comment: @4per , Это я для примера)

Comment: ок. Подскажите, ещё эти ваши class..class5 это именно названия классов, а Go статический метод? или это объекты разных классов, а Go методы экземпляров?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно еще короче:

```
var actions = new ThreadStart[] { class.Go, class2.Go, class3.Go, class4.Go, class5.Go };
foreach (var action in actions)
    new Thread(action).Start();
```

Для варианта с `Task`:

```
var actions = new Action[] { class.Go, class2.Go, class3.Go, class4.Go, class5.Go };
foreach (var action in actions)
    Task.Run(action);
```

Но тут есть тонкость: задачи выполняются в фоновом потоке - и, скорее всего, вы захотите дождаться их выполнения перед окончанием работы. В таком случае можно сделать вот так:

```
var actions = new Action[] { class.Go, class2.Go, class3.Go, class4.Go, class5.Go };
var tasks = actions.Select(action => Task.Run(action)).ToArray();

// ...

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Или вот так:

```
var actions = new Action[] { class.Go, class2.Go, class3.Go, class4.Go, class5.Go };
var task = Task.WhenAll(actions.Select(action => Task.Run(action)));

// ...

task.Wait();
```

Comment: А если мне необходимо дождаться выполнения добавив Join(); для определенного класса, и затем продолжить... Где в 1 примере можно это сделать?

Comment: @ArteS вы же говорили, что ваш код - одинаковый... Откуда вдруг взялся *определенный* класс?

Answer (score 4):

Решение 1 и 2 применимо для статических методов, 3 - нет.

## 1

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[]
{
   new Thread(class1.Go),
   new Thread(class2.Go),
   new Thread(class3.Go),
   new Thread(class4.Go),
   new Thread(class5.Go)  
}; 
foreach(var thr in threads)
   thr.Start();
```

---

## 2

```
var thrstarts = new ThreadStart[]
{
    new ThreadStart(class0.Go),
    new ThreadStart(class1.Go),
    new ThreadStart(class2.Go),
    new ThreadStart(class3.Go),
    new ThreadStart(class4.Go),
    new ThreadStart(class5.Go)                
};

foreach (var thrstart in thrstarts)
{
    new Thread(thrstart).Start();
}
```

---

## 3

Если у нас несколько клаcсов, имеющих метод Go() с одинаковой сигнатурой.

Создать интерфейс

```
public interface ICanGo
{        
    void Go();
}
```

Отметить, что классы реализуют интерфейс

```
class Class5 : ICanGo
{ ...
```

Вызов

```
ICanGo[] arr = new ICanGo[]
{        
    new Class1(),
    new Class2(),
    new Class3(),
    new Class4(),
    new Class5()
};

foreach (var item in arr)
{
    new Thread(item.Go).Start();
}
```

---

P.S. как тут на ruSo научили, Thread в таком контексте использовать стоит только в .Net 3.5 и ниже. Выше есть `Task`

P.P.S создание интерфейса всё равно полезно даже с `Task`

Comment: Уже что-то) Спасибо) А для Task подобное?

Comment: @ArteS А что подобное-то? `Task`, в отличии от `Thread`, создается и запускается одним вызовом метода